# Java Binary String to File

Tags: java, io

I have a File converted into Binary String (Example) `String = "101001010101"` and I need this to write this String to a file.

I get this binary String as :

```
File -> byte[] -> FileInputStream -> String
```

How can I convert this back to a file ?

Comment: For a member with 2,416 reputation that's a really bad question. I actually can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Dariusz Wawer with out complaining why dont you gain some points ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Unless this is some kind of exercise, storing binary data in a string as 0 and 1 characters is a really bad idea. It uses 16 times as much memory as necessary.

Comment: Why would you take a `File` object which is a wrapper for a path, convert it into a `byte[]` which you somehow convert into a file which you read back into a String which you then want to write as text encoded binary to a file again.

Comment: come on... this is really in all IO tutorials in Java, I mean the question could have some meaning if you would need to optimize your code, or looking for alternative or better solutions. That shows you worked on the issue, and you need some help to improve what you have.

Comment: Are you trying anything with Serialization ??

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class from commons-io. This will help you for such manipulations.